# Check the value returned from outside the function scope

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, es6-promise

I have this value which I obtained from the fetch request which is outside my calling function scope. How can i compare this against a a value.

```
let h=isCodeExists(userInput).then(res => console.log(res));
```

I want to check if this value ==2

Answer (score 1):

As the response will only come later, you need to make the comparison also later, i.e. it should be done in the `then` callback:

```
isCodeExists(userInput).then(res => {
    console.log(res);
    if (res == 2) console.log("it is 2!!");
    // Any other logic that needs the value of `res` should come here...
});
```